# JPQL Query - get child item in list from a parent

Tags: jpql

How would I create a JPQL query to get a **Record** if it exists in a **Folder** when I have the **Folder** *:id* and the **Record** *:refId* (named parameters). I would like to have the **Record** returned back from the query as there is other data that is part of the **Record** needed.

Here are the entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Folder {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Record.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECORD_FOLDER_0")
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    private List<Record> records;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Record {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "refId")
    private Long refId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "data", length = 255)
    private String data;
    ...
}
```

The regular SQL would look something like:

```java
.createNativeQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM record r WHERE r.refId=%d AND r.RECORD_FOLDER_0=%d", refId, folderId));
```

I am struggling on how to use a JPQL query to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a reference to the parent `Folder` from `Record`, you'll have to start with the `Folder` and join the child `Record`s. Something like this should do the trick:

```
TypedQuery<Record> q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT r FROM Folder f JOIN f.records r " +
    "WHERE f.id = :folderId AND r.refId = :refId", Record.class);
q.setParameter("folderId", folderId);
q.setParameter("refId", refId);
```

Comment: This worked great! I was not aware of resultClass argument option.